# serilog write to stringbuilder

Tags: c#, serilog

I am using Serilog for my logging in .net core.  I am wondering if there is a way to write the logs into a StringBuilder or similiar object where my program has access to the entire string log of the current run.  I can then email this entire string or do something else with it.

Basically I want access to the string of the entire log so far in the execution of my program.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-email, and read this for making your own sinks, https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Developing-a-sink

Answer (score 2):

[`Serilog.Sinks.InMemory`](https://github.com/serilog-contrib/SerilogSinksInMemory) is a Serilog sinks that buffers all the log output and gives you access to all log events.

https://github.com/serilog-contrib/SerilogSinksInMemory

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom sink and add it to Serilog.

From the [GitHub Wiki](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Provided-Sinks) page,

> Serilog provides sinks for writing log events to storage in various
> formats.

There is already a Email sink available in Serilog, and it might be helpful: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-email

To answer your question, you can add the log events to a string builder using the following code (I havent't tested it yet), but if you are just looking to email the logs, stick to the `Serilog.Sinks.Email` library.

```
public class MySink : ILogEventSink
{
    private readonly IFormatProvider _formatProvider;

    private StringBuilder _stringBuilder;

    public MySink(IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        _formatProvider = formatProvider;
        _stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public void Emit(LogEvent logEvent)
    {
        var message = logEvent.RenderMessage(_formatProvider);
        _stringBuilder.Append(message);
    }
}
```

You can read more about making your own sinks here, [github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Developing-a-sink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Developing-a-sink)

Answer (score 0):

There a serilog textwriter sink, which you can put a StringWriter with a StringBuilder
on.
See the example at: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-textwriter

```
var content = new StringBuilder();
var messages = new StringWriter(content);

var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.TextWriter(messages)
    .CreateLogger();
```